# Dynamodb golang - scan returns only one item

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I followed this example - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/go_2_dynamodb_code_examples.html

Here's my code:

```
    items, err := db.Scan(ctx, &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName: aws.String("Items"),
        Limit:     aws.Int32(1000),
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

This code always returns only the last added item

Any suggestions?

Query does the same

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you do not supply the `Limit` argument? How many items does awscli table scan return?

Answer (score 0):

If your table named `Items` had more than a single item they would all be returned. As you do not filter any data, then it should supply up to 1000 or 1MB of data, whichever comes first.

You should double check your table in the web console to ensure it has more items than you are being returned. And if you do have more items, double check your account and region are correct.

Failing that, share your entire code.